# How to Add Custom Timezones to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, linux, sqlalchemy

Im new to SQL and as such have some questions.
Currently I have loaded timezone in MySQL and us the following command to display the TZ names.

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone_name;
```

I would like to add a custom Timezone *without* reloading the whole table . For example, `US/Hawaii` is the `TZ` I need but say I want to add a `TZ` like `US/Hawaii-Aleutian` but to point at the same `TZ` as `US/HAwaii` or any another timezone I want. Is this possible?

I want to do this because I would like to use this new `TZ` with the following:

```
SELECT convert_tz(now(), "Canada/Mountain", "US/Hawaii-Aleutian")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a timezone name alias by inserting a row into the `mysql.time_zone_name` table.

For example,

```
 INSERT INTO mysql.time_zone_name 
             (Name, Time_zone_id)
 SELECT 'US/Whatever' Name, Time_zone_id
   FROM  mysql.time_zone_name
  WHERE  Name = 'US/Hawaii'
```

**But**: This is a *seriously* bad idea. The [zoneinfo tables](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) are updated routinely via Linux distro updates as various jurisdictions change their time zone and daylight savings time policies. Your change to MySQL's timezone tables will get erased whenever those updates are applied to your server. Just ask your users to use either `US/Hawaii`, `US/Aleutian`, or maybe `Pacific/Honolulu`.

Comment: Thanks Ollie for the fast responce